# Set cursor in HTML

Tags: html, textbox, inputbox

I want to create a webpage which contains an input box, and a button.

The Input-Box is for a Barcode-Scanner, a number which has been scanned, should be written to that input box., the problem is now, when i enter the page, the input field has no cursor in it, i have to click in it first.

Is there a way to set a cursor by default in the box? like open the page and be ready to scan?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `html5` you can use the `autofocus` attribute.

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```

Or you can set the focus on load

```
window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('idOfTextbox').focus();
}
```

Comment: @sgtBear anywhere inside `<script>` tag